# How to download App Engine Source Code from Google Cloud Console?

Tags: google-app-engine, download, cloud

Sometimes we forget to backup our code. But the code is in the cloud running on App Engine. So you want to download it. Well here is the solution. Reason I am posting this is all the current stack overflow solutions out there are outdated (deprecated methods).

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the your projects google cloud console --> choose the "Storage" product in left hand sidebar --> the bucket of "staging..appspot.com" --> open <country.gcr.io> folder -->  folder --> version you want.
[image]

PS: (find your active version by going to the your projects google cloud console --> choose the "App Engine" product in left hand sidebar --> navigate in side bar to "versions" --> take note of the version of your app that is currently being served. Copy this and use it to locate with .tar source code file you want.[image]