# Download source code from Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: json, google-app-engine, download

I have been trying to download/extract the source code for an application in the google app engine.  I found this more current post, [How to download App Engine Source Code from Google Cloud Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64122706/how-to-download-app-engine-source-code-from-google-cloud-console), but I do not see any files or folders in the staging bucket.  My login is an owner of the project.  I have also tried the appcfg.py commands but receive the authentication error below.  Is this because this is deprecated?  Or are there some other permissions my login requires?

<ApiError 401, Message: "Rejected by creds_policy: Permission 'auth.creds.useNormalUserEUC' not granted to app-engine-appserver@prod.google.com, because it satisfies none of the 3 rules granting that permission. (Policy {type=creds, id=/apps/framework/auth/v0/mapping0/80102d58-16e4-455f-bf24-13feb564b751}); RpcSecurityPolicy http://rpcsp/p/9aw5LWxoo9BLqcVKVlGreN0-Q5-wt_0mk2RWLjm140U
com.google.security.context.validation.CredsPermissionException: Rejected by creds_policy: Permission 'auth.creds.useNormalUserEUC' not granted to app-engine-appserver@prod.google.com, because it satisfies none of the 3 rules granting that permission. (Policy {type=creds, id=/apps/framework/auth/v0/mapping0/80102d58-16e4-455f-bf24-13feb564b751}); RpcSecurityPolicy http://rpcsp/p/9aw5LWxoo9BLqcVKVlGreN0-Q5-wt_0mk2RWLjm140U ">